# Select * From java with preparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I faced this problem today with my select SQL. This method is supposed to show data from database in tex tfields. I changed it from statement to preparedStatement, but I faced a problem.

```
 public Entreprise loadDataModify(String id) { 
    Entreprise e = new Entreprise();
    PreparedStatement stmt;

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE mail=?";
        stmt = cnx.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, id);
        

        ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rst.next()) {
            stmt.setString(2, e.getNom());
            stmt.setString(3, e.getEmail());
            stmt.setString(4, e.getTel());
            stmt.setString(5, e.getOffre());

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }
    return e;

}
```

It shows i have problem with syntax and the output is " nu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not filling your `Enterprise` object. And you are not using `executeQuery()` function correctly. As seen below, the parameter inside the brackets has been removed. `PreparedStatement`s first of all need the values of the parameters (your `?` in the query) and then the formed query has to be executed. If you give a `String` parameter to `executeQuery()` then the query in the brackets will be executed.

And the part where `Enterprise` is being filled could be seen below.

This would be the correct way:

```java
public Entreprise loadDataModify(String id) { 
    Entreprise e = new Entreprise();
    PreparedStatement stmt;

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE mail=?";
        stmt = cnx.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, id);
        

        ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rst.next()) 
        {
            // rst keeps the data, so you have to traverse it and get the data from it in this way.
            e.setNom( rst.getString("HERE EITHER THE COLUMN NAME OR INDEX"));
            e.setEmail( rst.getString("HERE EITHER THE COLUMN NAME OR INDEX"));
            e.setTel( rst.getString("HERE EITHER THE COLUMN NAME OR INDEX"));
            e.setOffre( rst.getString("HERE EITHER THE COLUMN NAME OR INDEX"));

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }
    return e;

}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but you did not explain the OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the wrong method. Unlike Statement, when you're using a PreperedStatement you should first set the values for the parameters, and after you can call on that instance executeQuery() method.
Also, it's a best practice to use **try-with-resources**, because a Statement or PreparedStament object is a **Resource** (a resource is a class that implements *AutoCloseable* interface) and you have to close it. Using try-with-resources, it's done automatically.
The ResultSet instance is also a resource, but it's closed when the statement object is closed, so you don't have to close it explicitly.
So, the best way to solve your problem will be:

```
 String selectAllByMail = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE mail=?";
    try (PreparedStatement prpStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectAllByMail)) {
        // use prpStatement
        prpStatement.setString(1, id);
        ResultSet resultSet = prpStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            // process resultSet

        }
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `executeQuery()` should *not* be passing the query string.  Use this version:

```java
String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE mail=?";
stmt = cnx.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, id);

ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rst.next()) {
    // process result set
}
```

Your current code is actually calling some overloaded `Statement#executeQuery()` method, which is not the version of the method which you want to be calling.